# Wire-shark network traffic dump

Tags: networking, wireshark, network-traffic

I have a question to answer for one of my classes. But I'm having some trouble finding the information on this.

"So you have network traffic dumps as files on a USB given by the victims. How can you know that it is accurate? List some of the ways that it could have been changed. What things would you look for within the dump file that might indicate tampering."

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a self study assignment, there are no lecture

Comment: Read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/DidIJustGetOwned) - I believe it'll help.

Comment: thanks a lot, that link seems to have some information!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tampering data and not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alfasin. Your link helped,

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/DidIJustGetOwned